# Conversion between DMS Formats in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinates, degrees-minutes-seconds

A point vector layer was added to QGIS, after exporting the layer to .xlsx the coordinates in wkt format were attached to the table.

In QGis I added additional columns x and y, to assign a coordinates in **DMS format** to each geometry. I filled that columns with tool '*Field Calculator*', with the formula:

```
to_dms(x(transform($geometry,'EPSG:3765','EPSG:4326')), 'x', 3)
to_dms(y(transform($geometry,'EPSG:3765','EPSG:4326')), 'y', 3)
```

and  that part works fine.

But I get the coordinates in format:

**40°31'21.365"**

**Is it possible in QGIS to get coordinates in the format:**

**403121N**

[image]

**EDIT:**

I have solution but now I have in my format N (north) and E (east) but I expect N and W, does anyone have an idea why this is so?

[image]

Comment: In my personal opinion the person who authorized the last two notation styles should be forced to georeference scanned 1970s planning documents for the rest of their life. That being said - since this is a matter to text manipulation, you should be able to achieve this.

Comment: @Erik I absolutely agree, I think it is completely vague and unnecessary with the other options

Comment: Is the transformation from EPSG:3765 to EPSG:4326 correct? West values are outside the bounds of EPSG:3765 anyway, aren't they? But that shouldn't matter, I think.

Comment: @Kasluk24 Thank you, I didn't think about it, that was the point , EPSG:3765 has axis :    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
AXIS["Northing",NORTH].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To get DMS format e.g. 403121N in QGIS we can use 'Field Calculator' with formula for e.g.

   ```
   ddmmss(y(transform($geometry,'EPSG:3765','EPSG:4326')),x(transform($geometry,'EPSG:3765','EPSG:4326')),'yx',0,'')
   ```
2. In the format of DMS labels E and N or N and W, depend on the coordinate system we use. It is necessary to check the axes for the coordinate system we use (this can be checked  at e.g. https://epsg.io/3765)

Comment: official registry is epsg.org, WKT url would be https://epsg.org/crs/wkt/id/3765

Comment: @nmtoken  maybe a better option is eg https://epsg.io/3765

Comment: Sure, it's just a matter of opinion.  epsg.io is third party, and can be out of date, so if you want definitive answers then use the official registry,  the URL of epsg.io is neater though.  I gave the WKT link on the registry, but query interface gives a nice web page that allows you to drill down through all the components which I quite like